# Magento orders going to close after only one return

Tags: creditmemo

As an example if a customer purchase 5 items and later returns 1 the order closes after that first return. Is there a way to keep the order open so that we can do more returns if needed?

Comment: Which version of Magento? Is the order invoiced? What is the status of the items in the database? Can you reproduce on a screencast?

Comment: Magento CE 1.9.1. It was invoiced. The order shows closed.  If I don't select the timeframe allowed for returns in the RMA admin does a default value apply?